# where is postgresql-docs pdf?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

So I installed postgresql-docs:

```
[root@me ~]# yum info postgresql93-docs.x86_64
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Installed Packages
Name        : postgresql93-docs
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 9.3.14
Release     : 1.62.amzn1
Size        : 13 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : amzn-main
Summary     : Extra documentation for PostgreSQL
URL         : http://www.postgresql.org/
License     : PostgreSQL
Description : The postgresql-docs package contains some additional documentation for
            : PostgreSQL.  Currently, this includes the main documentation in PDF format
            : and source files for the PostgreSQL tutorial.
```

And cheked docs:

```
[root@me ~]# find / -name *.pdf
/usr/share/doc/python27-babel-0.9.4/doc/logo.pdf
/usr/share/doc/libtasn1-2.3/libtasn1.pdf
```

None found! Only `/usr/share/doc/postgresql93-docs-9.3.14/html` has html docs.

**Q:** Is it bad package description or where in directory structure can I find that pdf file?..

Comment: You can always download it from the Postgres homepage: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/manuals/

Comment: Yes, I know. Thanks! I meant - in which directory should I look for it

Comment: You must have a special use case because pdf is hard...

Comment: `rpm -ql postgresql93-docs.x86_64`?

Comment: @Abelisto `4# rpm -ql postgresql93-docs.x86_64 | grep pgf
/usr/share/doc/postgresql93-docs-9.3.14/html/pgfreespacemap.html
` all files html and css

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I wanted one file, not directory. But it's not the point. I can easily download it. It seems the description is wrong - there's no pdf in package